# Can't access http://localhost after sideloading

Tags: iis, win-universal-app

my app UWP  is accessing some data by IIS,

```
 public static async Task<List<Uri>> GetMedia()
        {
            List<Uri> target = new List<Uri>();
            HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var urlVideos = "http://localhost/Videos";
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(urlVideos);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            string htmlString = result;

            document.LoadHtml(htmlString);
            var collection = document.DocumentNode.DescendantsAndSelf()  ;
            foreach (HtmlNode link in collection)
            {
                if (link.Attributes.Contains("href") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(link.Attributes["href"].Value.Trim().Trim('/')))
                {
                    target.Add(new Uri("http://localhost" + link.Attributes["href"].Value));
                }
            }
            return target;
        }
```

then I am calling that method like this,

private IList _videos
 _videos = await Proxy.GetMedia();

it runs well except after I sideloaded the app ,where I just realized that _video stays empty,and I can browse http://localhost/Videos  so i assumed that   IIS is  well configured,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access localhost from a sideloaded app you have to enable network loopback for this specific app. Per default access to http://localhost is forbidden for every app. 
You can run this command on commandline:

```
checknetisolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=YourAppContainerPackageFamilyName
```

Replace YourAppContainerPackageFamilyName with the AppContainer Name of your app. You find it in  *.appxmanifest of your app. You have to run this on the machine where you sideloaded the app. On dev machines it is enabled per default. 
See also this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx

Comment: Hi,Damiel thanks but I am getting error when I am running this command error 1337 -538

Comment: Ok, I modified this answer slightly. If you take the Packagefamilyname from your app, the parameter is -n not -p. I could repro your issue. If you use the command above with -n it will work.

Comment: Great, glad to hear this bob!

Comment: Thank you! Saved us quite a bit of time and frustration.